# ReferenceError: variable is not define - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

oddsData is undefined when i want to run the code below.

```
getOdds = async(data) => {
    var receivedData = "";
    send({"Command":"GetMatchMarkets","Params":data});
    var message = JSON.stringify({"Command":"GetMatchMarkets","Params":data});
    var length = Buffer.byteLength(message),
    buffer = new Buffer(4 + Buffer.byteLength(message));
    buffer.writeUInt32LE(length, 0);
    buffer.write(message, 4);
    client.write(buffer);
    var bytesToReceive =  length;
    var oddsData = "";
    client.on('data', async(buf) =>  {
        function calc(){
            var offset = 0;
            if (bytesToReceive === 0) { 
                if(buf.length < 4){ return; } 
                bytesToReceive = buf.readUInt32LE(0);
                offset = 4;
            }
            var currentCommandBytes = Math.min(bytesToReceive, buf.length - offset);
            receivedData += buf.slice(offset, offset + currentCommandBytes);
            bytesToReceive -= currentCommandBytes;
            if (bytesToReceive === 0) { 
                bytesToReceive = 0;
                if (receivedData != ""){
                    oddsData += receivedData;
                }
                receivedData = "";
            }
            if (currentCommandBytes < buf.length - offset) {  
                calc(buf.slice(currentCommandBytes+offset))
            }
        }
        await calc();
    });
    console.log(oddsData);
}
```

return ReferenceError: oddsData is not defined.

oddsData is undefined when i want to run the code below.

Comment: Do you use oddsData in your ...OTHER CODES... ?

Comment: The way your code is written, the `console.log(oddsData);` should show an empty string for `oddsData` because the `client.on('data', ...)` event handler has not yet run when you do the `console.log(oddsData);`. `client.on('data, ...)` registers an event handler to be called sometime in the future whenever that event occurs.  Meanwhile, right after you register the event handler, but before the event has ever occurred, you do `console.log(oddsData);` so of course, `oddsData` is still unchanged.

Comment: I renewed the codes

Comment: Which line of code is causing the ReferenceError?

Comment: You updated the code, but everything I said in my previous comment is still true.  If you want to do `console.log(oddsData)` to see the changes in the event handler, then you need to put the `console.log(oddsData)` INSIDE the event handler.  That's where the variable gets changed.  You're still logging the value BEFORE the event handler has ever been called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used oddsData in in your ...OTHER CODES..., maybe the error is due to those nesting of functions,
Declare functions as variables and then pass it to your code.

```js
function test(){

var calc = function (){
     ...OTHER CODES....
     receivedData = "";
     return oddsdata
}

var asFun = async (buf) =>  {
        await calc();
    }
var oddsData = "";
    client.on('data', asFun);
    console.log(oddsData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[updated to match changes in question's code]

Stripping out all the code that doesn't affect `oddsData` leaves the following structure:

```js
const getOdds = async () => {

  var oddsData = '';

  client.on('data', async () => {

    function calc () {
      oddsData += 'something';
    }

    await calc();
  });

  console.log(oddsData);
};
```

I see no indication that `oddsData` should be undefined.

A little test program to explore what's happening:

```js
const getOdds = async() => {

  result.innerHTML += 'enter getOdds async()\n';

  var oddsData = "";

  client.addEventListener('data', async() => {

    result.innerHTML += `client.on data async() oddsData:  '${oddsData}'\n`;

    function calc() {
      oddsData += "calc!";
      result.innerHTML += `calc() oddsData: '${oddsData}'\n`;
    }

    await calc();

  });

  result.innerHTML += `getOdds async() oddsData: '${oddsData}'\n`;
};

window.onload = () => {
  result.innerHTML = 'window.onload calling getOdds()\n';
  getOdds();
}
```

```html
<p id="client">This is client.
  <button onclick="emitData()">Emit 'data' to client</button>
</p>

<p>Results:</p>
<pre id="result"></pre>
<script>
  const client = document.getElementById('client');
  const result = document.getElementById('result');

  function emitData() {
    let event = new Event('data');
    client.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
</script>
```